# How to debug the firebase rules effectivity?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Current, I am developing and testing the firebase database rules on the Firebase console. Is this possible to do it in a test case? I would like to create the rule, and allow me to inject different data and test my rules. It seems that the Firebase console is limited to do so. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

firebase have it's own simulator for rules for read and write operations, for the write and validation operation you can write your data as JSON and it will show you if it works or not and the rules where the problem is. go to `console > database > rules > click on SIMULATOR.`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any way to debug what things like "newData" actually are/contain etc?

Comment: unfortunately no